# Великий Лебовс(ь)кі чи Лебовський? І як у жіночому роді?

Tags: переклад, from-english, правопис, власні-назви

Чомусь всюди пишуть "Лебовскі" або "Лебовські".
Постало питання, як же ж правильно передавати подібні прізвища.

Правопис 2019 року подає таке правило, с. 145:

> 10. Суфікси слов’янських прізвищ -ск(ий), -цк(ий), -ск(і), -цк(і), -sk(i),
>     -ck(i), -dzk(i), -sk(ý), -ck(ý) передаємо відповідно через -ськ(ий), -цьк(ий), - дзьк(ий): Бронéвський, Даргомúжський, Маякóвський, Мýсоргський, Острóвський; Гомулúцький, Городéцький; Грýдзький,
>     Завáдзький; так само з ь пишемо російські прізвища на -ск(ой),
>     -цк(ой): Луговськúй (Луговськá), Трубецькúй (Трубецькá).

Тож правильно буде "Лебовський"? А в жіночому "Лебовська"?
Власне, чи можна стверджувати, що це саме слов'янске прізвище?